# SQL: ORA-00933 error in select

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm trying to perform a somewhat complex select from 3 tables, all joined by a b_id:

```
select max(bs.b_id), 
       h.b_type_id, 
       t.name_id 
  from b_state as bs, 
       t_info as t, 
       history as h 
 where bs.b_id = t.b_id 
   and bs.b_id = h.b_id 
   and t.name_id in (???) 
   and bs.is_detached = ? 
 group by h.b_type_id, 
          t.name_id
```

In MySQL it gives exactly what I want, but it seems to fail in PSQL and Oracle, plus execution in Oracle results in: "`ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`" (which usually occurs in INSERT queries as Google suggests).

I suppose there is a DB independent way to do the same. Please advice.

Comment: How are you executing this query in Oracle - ie. via JDBC, ODBC, through SQLPlus ...?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try:

```
select max(bs.b_id), h.b_type_id, t.name_id 
  from b_state bs
  inner join t_info t on bs.b_id = t.b_id
  inner join history h on bs.b_id = h.b_id
  where t.name_id in (???) and bs.is_detached = ?
  group by h.b_type_id, t.name_id
```

Comment: That is the problem. I've used `iner joins` for a better readability.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select max(bs.b_id),
       h.b_type_id,
       t.name_id
  from b_state bs,
       t_info t,
       history h
 where bs.b_id = t.b_id
   and bs.b_id = h.b_id
   and t.name_id in (???)
   and bs.is_detached = ?
 group by h.b_type_id,
          t.name_id
```

The "as" aliasing the tables was causing you a problem in Oracle.

EDIT: I have used the SQL-86 syntax as that is what you originally posted but you should really be using the SQL-92 syntax by default.

Comment: Thanks for a suggestion. Unfortunately it takes few hours to check the test in all DBs, but I definitely would.

Answer (score 1):

Oracle uses `:varname` to bind variables instead of `?`.

So try something like

```
select 
  max(bs.b_id),
  h.b_type_id,
  t.name_id    
from 
  b_state as bs,
  t_info  as t,
  history as h  
where 
  bs.b_id = t.b_id            and 
  bs.b_id = h.b_id            and 
  t.name_id in (:1, :2, :3)   and 
  bs.is_detached = :4
group by 
 h.b_type_id,           
 t.name_id
```

Answer (score 1):

I suggest giving an alias to the max and (if necessary) comma-separating the parameters in the `in` clause, like so:

```
select max(bs.b_id) max_b_id, 
       h.b_type_id, 
       t.name_id 
  from b_state as bs, 
       t_info as t, 
       history as h 
 where bs.b_id = t.b_id 
   and bs.b_id = h.b_id 
   and t.name_id in (?,?,?) 
   and bs.is_detached = ? 
 group by h.b_type_id, 
          t.name_id
```